# How to manipulate an SVG line using an HTML slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I have an example of moving an SVG line using an HTML slider. Now it moves the horizontal line up and down via an HTML slider. Next I would like it to move up and down as well as scale inwards (from the center). It needs to scale smaller as it moves downward, and larger as it moves upward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Move The Line</title>
    <style>
      .vert1Slider {
        width: 150px;
        height: 20px;
      }
      #vert1Display {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: small;
        margin-top: -20px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      .slider {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #d3d3d3;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 0.5;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
      }
      .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #4caf50;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #4caf50;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- SVG Vertical Position Line Slider -->
    <svg class="moveTheLine" id="svg2" width="150" height="80">
      <rect width="300" height="300" fill="#eee"></rect>
      <line
        id="testLine"
        x1="39"
        y1="28"
        x2="111"
        y2="28"
        fill="none"
        id="svg_line"
        stroke="#000000"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-width="5"
      />
    </svg>
    <!-- END - SVG Vertical Position Line Slider -->

    <!-- HTML Vertical Position Line Slider -->
    <div class="vert1Slider">
      <input
        id="vert1Range"
        type="range"
        min=".5"
        max="1.5"
        value="1"
        step=".05"
        class="slider"
      />
      <p id="vert1Display">Vertical Position <span id="vertScalar"></span></p>
    </div>
    <!-- END - HTML Vertical Position Line Slider -->

    <!-- JS Vertical Position Line Slider -->
    <script>
      var sliderVert1 = document.getElementById("vert1Range"); //getter
      var outputVert1 = document.getElementById("vertScalar"); //getter
      var origVert1 = document.getElementById("testLine").getAttribute("y1"); //getter
      var origVert2 = document.getElementById("testLine").getAttribute("y2"); //getter
      console.log(origVert1, origVert2);
      outputVert1.innerHTML = sliderVert1.value;

      sliderVert1.oninput = function () {
        var newPathX1 = $(testLine).attr("x1"); //getter
        var newPathY1 = $(testLine).attr("y1"); //getter
        var newPathX2 = $(testLine).attr("x2"); //getter
        var newPathY2 = $(testLine).attr("y2"); //getter
        newX1 = newPathX1 * 1;
        newY1 = origVert1 * vert1Range.value;
        newX2 = newPathX2 * 1;
        newY2 = origVert2 * vert1Range.value;
        console.log(newX1, newY1);
        console.log(newX2, newY2);
        console.log(vert1Range.value);
        $(testLine).attr("x1", newX1); //setter
        $(testLine).attr("y1", newY1); //setter
        $(testLine).attr("x2", newX2); //setter
        $(testLine).attr("y2", newY1); //setter
        outputVert1.innerHTML = this.value;
      };
    </script>
    <!-- END - JS Vertical Position Line Slider -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my example code:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/harbin_bill/0zw945m8/17/
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the line equation.

1. find the point coordinates at the upper limit & assign them as x1,y1
2. find the point coordinates at the lower limit & assign them as x2,y2
3. use those coordinates to solve for point slope & slope intercept
4. solve the y=mx+b equation for x
5. insert the equation as newX1 & newX2 into my code

```
sliderVert1.oninput = function () {
    var newPathX1 = $(testLine).attr("x1"); //getter
    var newPathY1 = $(testLine).attr("y1"); //getter
    var newPathX2 = $(testLine).attr("x2"); //getter
    var newPathY2 = $(testLine).attr("y2"); //getter
    newY1 = origVert1 * vert1Range.value;
    newX1 = (5 * newY1 + 133) / 7;
    newY2 = origVert2 * vert1Range.value;
    newX2 = -((5 * newY2 - 917) / 7);
    console.log(Math.round(newX1), Math.round(newY1));
    console.log(Math.round(newX2), Math.round(newY2));
    console.log(vert1Range.value);
    $(testLine).attr("x1", newX1); //setter
    $(testLine).attr("y1", newY1); //setter
    $(testLine).attr("x2", newX2); //setter
    $(testLine).attr("y2", newY1); //setter
    outputVert1.innerHTML = this.value;
  };
```

Here is my example code:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/harbin_bill/0kduvj8z/1/
```